# Await function doesn't work with mongo DB collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having trouble capturing the current collection in mongodb.

I have a file with FetchUsers function which returns a collection with users:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-url>.sdzp0ug.mongodb.net/? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const fetchUsers= () => { 
   const connectionParams = {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
}
 try{
   mongoose.connect(uri);

  } catch (error)
   {
    console.log(error);
   }

 const collectionName = 'UsersTests'
 const Users = mongoose.model(collectionName, new mongoose.Schema({}));

Users .find({}, function(err, docs) {
if (err) {
  console.error(err);
  return;
}
console.log(`Documents in ${collectionName}:`);
mongoose.connection.close();
console.log(`My current collection: ${docs}`);
return docs;
});
}

module.exports = fetchUsers
```

In another file I have a function that takes the returned value and then displays it:

```
const fetchData = require("../../controllers/USersControllers/fetchUsers.js");

  async function displayUsers() {
     let users = await fetchData();
     console.log(users);
    }

  module.exports = displayUsers;
```

and all this is running on the express server

```
const express = require("express");
const displayUsers =  require("./public/js/displayUsers.js");
const app = express();




app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.listen(5000, () => {
 console.log("Server started on port 3000");

 displayUsers();
});
```

The problem is that displayUsers displays undefined and doesn't wait until fetchData returns a collection.

Comment: `fetchUsers` doesn't return anything.

Comment: You are returning from the callback passed to `Users.finds`. This does not magically return from the outer function. This might help you understand callbacks: [JavaScript: How (not) to get a value "out of" a callback](https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I corrected the code and it works.

GetUsersModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uri =
 "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-url>.sdzp0ug.mongodb.net/? 
  retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const connectionParams = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };
  try {
    mongoose.connect(
     uri
     );
    console.log("Database conected!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log("Database connection failed");
   }

 const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
   content: String,
   title: String,
   author: String,
 });

 const Users =    
                    mongoose.model.userTest || 
                     mongoose.model("userTest", Schema);
   

   module.exports = Users;
```

fetchUsersData.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Users = 
 require("../controllers/SnippetsControllers/GetSnippetModel.js");

const uri =
 "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-url>.sdzp0ug.mongodb.net/? 
  retryWrites=true&w=majority";


const fetchUsers = () => {
const connectionParams = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}
try{
  
mongoose.connect(uri);
  console.log('Database conected!!!!!')
  
} catch (error)
{
  console.log(error);
  console.log('Database connection failed')
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Users.find({}, function(err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(docs);
      }
    });
  });

}

module.exports = fetchUsers;
```

UseUsersData.js

```
const fetchData = require("../models/fetchUsersData");
async function displayUsers(req) {
  let usersContainer = [];
try  {
    let users = await fetchData();
    let usersArray = users;

    console.log(usersArray);

   } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
 }
}
```